# O padrão REST permite o uso de query string?

Tags: rest, http, url, rotas, querystring

A maioria dos frameworks que conheço usam parâmetros pela URL da seguinte forma:

```
/recurso/variavel
```

Por exemplo

```
/produtos/{nome}
/produtos/{categoria}
```

Alguns usam entre `{}` outros `<>`, etc

Para diferenciar as buscas geralmente se passa além do valor para filtrar, o campo que será filtrado:

```
/recurso/campo/variavel
```

Por exemplo

```
/produtos/nome/{nome}
/produtos/categoria/{categoria}
```

Mas se quiser fazer buscas mais complexas, filtrando por mais de um campo, se cria muitas rotas, com diversos parâmetros:

```
/produtos/categoria/{categoria}/nome/{nome}/precoMinimo/{minPreco}/precoMaximo/{maxPreco}
```

Se o usuário quiser pesquisar por categoria, preço mínimo e máximo, tem que criar outra rota ou usar essa passando o valor do nome em branco. Acho que é o suficiente para entender como isso torna complexo fazer e dar manutenção

O uso de *query string* pode faicilitar, criando apenas uma rota para cada recurso, e adicionando apenas uma condição pra cada campo que deseja usar no filtro, se existe ou não. Isso também pode ser implementado com loop apartir de um array com as chaves dos parâmetros

Já que facilita tando, por que não usar? O padrão REST não permite ou limita seu uso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O REST é um estilo arquitetural que utiliza o HTTP como forma representativa, desta forma, ele sim tanto permite quanto suporta a utilização de query strings.

Várias bibliotecas possuem opções para incluir query strings durante a requisição, a biblioteca [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/) do Java por exemplo utiliza a implementação [javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), que possui a definição do método `queryParam`.

Visto que não existe nenhum padrão à ser seguido em relação à montagem de APIs REST, cada desenvolvedor pode definir como vai utilizar ou montar sua API, utilizando ou não este recurso.

Particularmente, em projetos, eu sigo a seguinte regra:

- O parâmetro é obrigatório para localizar uma entidade?

  Tratar o parâmetro como parte hierárquica do caminho (*path*) / URI

  **Exemplo:** Buscar um usuário por um id específico `GET usuarios/{id}`
- O parâmetro **NÃO** é obrigatório para localizar uma entidade, mas provê detalhes importantes que podem ajudar a localizá-la?

  Tratar o parâmetro como parte não hierárquica do caminho, um complemento à requisição (query string)

  **Exemplo:** Buscar todas as notificações do usuário `GET notificacoes/usuario/{id}` / Buscar todas as notificações do usuário para um sistema específico `GET notificacoes/usuario/{id}?sistema=x`

No segundo exemplo, é possível obter um resultado apenas informando o usuário, porém, caso queira as notificações para um sistema em específico, não tem problema, é possível utilizar o mesmo método e endpoint.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) - Definição de Path (hierárquico) e Query (não hierárquico) (inglês)